# What's the rule that users are visible in windows control panel?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to list users without `WDAGUtilityAccount` and other service accounts.
Just like the users list in the Windows Control Panel.

However, both `wmic` and `NetUserEnum(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT)` will show all users including `WDAGUtilityAccount`.

By my experience, the users shown in the Control Panel are users under Administrators / Users / Power Users / Guests, but I cannot find a document to prove this.

Is there a rule that filters out the service accounts like `WDAGUtilityAccount`?

Update:
`UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD` of `NET_DISPLAY_USER` that returned by`NetQueryDisplayInformation` indicates the user is created by control panel (not the users created in computer management), but the flag of Guest and DefaultAccount still makes no difference.

BTW, the SID may be another way to distinguish service account(501+) and normal account(1001+)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids

Comment: The key is "LocalAccount". So, with `wmic`, you probably want: `wmic UserAccount where "LocalAccount=True" get Name`

Comment: Nope, they are all LocalAccount=True
LocalAccount  Name
TRUE          Administrator
TRUE          DefaultAccount
TRUE          Guest
TRUE          norm
TRUE          WDAGUtilityAccount